# kafka partition assignment on 'consumers'

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I understand that kafka arranges data of a topic over many partitions, and consumers in one consumer group are assigned different partitions from where they can receive data:

```
 partition-1  partition-2  partition-3  partition-4  partition-5  partition-6
      |____________|            |____________|           |____________|
            |                         |                        |
       consumer-1                 consumer-2               consumer-3
```

My question is:

- The term `consumers`, are they identified by host/IP, or by client connection?

In other words, if I start two threads or processes, running the same kafka client code with same consumer group, are they considered one consumer or two consumers?

Comment: Should be easy to test if you are starting this app then describe the group... What have you seen?

Answer (score 0):

First, Consumers are not thread safe.

More than one instance in separate threads / processes would not be considered as the same client in the group, but they do display host information when you describe the consumer group